# Is there a way to fix " Umbraco.Core.pdb not loaded " error UMBRACO

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, umbraco

[image]

I don't know what happened but when I build the project, this error showed up.

Does anyone know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948290/no-symbols-have-been-loaded-and-pdb-file-missing

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have missed connection string details in web.config file.

I had  `<connectionStrings configSource=".\UmbracoConnectionDetails.config" />` in my web.config file but UmbracoConnectionDetails.config was missing in my root folder. Just has added file and working fine.